# Unexpected Results using "%" character in string ending with "\n" character

Tags: javascript

`console.log("%%%","\n");`

produces only two "%" characters and a newline (one of the percent signs is getting removed)

`console.log("%%%"+"\n");`

produces all 3 characters as expected....

if I replace the "%" character with any other character, both examples output 3 characters and a newline character....it is only with the "%" character that one of them gets removed.

https://replit.com/@JustJamie/PercentSignConfusion#index.js

I've tried searching for an explanation for this phenomenon but couldn't find any previous mention of this.  I've tried replacing the "%" character with many other characters, including all special characters, and only get this result using the % character.

While typing this question, I may have discovered the answer. I believe what is happening is that javascript is interpreting the % sign as a placeholder, and then replacing the last instance of the placeholder with the newline character from the second argument passed to console.log.  Can anyone find the javascript reference that explains this?

Comment: This is deliberate. Chrome provides a way to console log with custom styling in the log message. See https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/format-style/

Comment: Read about [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log). Its first argument is a format string.

Comment: If you want to ensure you don't apply the chrome formatting then put another string in the first parameter of the console log like this: console.log('', '\%\%\%', '\n')

Comment: Thank you @SteveTomlin and axiac ....if I understand correctly, basically, console.log calls string.format on the first argument passed to console.log and uses the subsequent arguments as substitutions....if the first argument has no placeholders, then the arguments to console.log are displayed separated by spaces

Answer (score 2):

`%` may be used for formatting in `console.log`. For instance, `%d` may be used to output a number.

```js
console.log('%d', 42);
```

`%%` is used to escape the percent sign, i.e. output a single percent symbol on its own.